# Zend_Date and setting timezone on instation

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-date

I have a ZF app and am saving times as UTC in MySQL db. When I retrieve, them I'd like to tell Zend_Ddate that they are UTC rather than the timezone set in php.ini of 'America/Los Angeles'.

Currently, I'm instantiating like this:

```
$date=new Zend_Date($item['created_on_utc'],Zend_Date::ISO_8601,'en_US');
```

but feel like there should be a way to tell Zend_Date that is a utc Date. How would I do that?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

> date_default_timezone_set —  Sets the
>   default timezone used by all date/time
>   functions in a script

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
```

Comment: +1, this is best set in your bootstrap. In fact, with E_STRICT enabled, PHP will complain whenever you are using a time function relying on the timezone.

Comment: this was already done index.php script. the issue is that I'm saving in UTC with locale associated with that save (in case user changes his / her locale at a future point). The issue is how do I decrement the 8 hrs from UTC to America / Los Angeles. It seems like I should be able to tell Zend_Date, you're getting UTC and I want it to be Pacific time zone